# What API/protocol is used to implement `Share` feature in windows explorer

Tags: windows, shell, share, explorer

I want to know the API or protocol of the Share feature in the windows explorer like this
[image]
Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ShowShareUIForWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-idatatransfermanagerinterop-showshareuiforwindow) (MSDN says it requires Windows 8 but it actually only works in Windows 10/11 in a normal desktop application).

[How do I show the sharing pane from a Win32 desktop application?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170315-00/?p=95735)